# Custom computed functions in Templatized `<template>`

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Using the Polymer `Templatizer` behaviour, let's say we have it all working and we want to not only `stamp` properties, but also computed functions, how should one go about this?

I can get it working by specifying

```
_getRootDataHost: function(){
  return this;
}
```

However it turns out that doing this means that

```
<my-element prop="[[value]]"></my-element>
```

actually breaks (as `value` is now looked for in `<my-element>` instead of it's parent).

Just to be clear, what the above allows is

```
<my-element>
 <template>
  <span>{{someComputedProperty(item)}}</span>
 </template>
</my-element>
```

where `someComputedProperty` is defined on `<my-element>` instead of it's container.

Answer (score 0):

So, one extremely ugly way to achieve this is to set the functions directly on the `dataHost`, so what we get is a function that is called in `attached` which looks like this

```
_registerEvilFunctions: function(){
    this.dataHost._pdt_getArrayItemLabel = this._getArrayItemLabel;
    this.dataHost._pdt_getValidRegexForInput = this._getValidRegexForInput;
}
```

Can't say I am happy with it, and I have made sure to prefix it plenty to prevent collisions, but at least it works.